# Django admin inline warning on new record

Tags: django, django-admin

This app assigns projects to an employee. Each assignment has a percent effort field. In a perfect world no employee's effort would exceed 100%, but this is an imperfect world. This code catches whan an effort is > 100% but throws an exception. What I want, however, is a warning and I've spent a few days trying to find something in the documentation.

```
class EmployeeAssignmentInLineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super(EmployeeAssignmentInLineFormSet, self).clean()
        effort = 0.0
        for assignment in self.cleaned_data:
            if not assignment['DELETE']:
                effort += assignment['effort']
        if effort > self.instance.fte * 100:
            raise ValidationError('Assignments exceed FTE equivalent')
```

Comment: Which version of Django?

Comment: 1.5 - looks like I need more characters or this won't post. Version 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`messages`](http://django.me/messages) app, but to add a message, you need access to the `request` object. So, maybe you can override the `save_formset` method on your `ModelAdmin` instead, something like:

```
from django.contrib import messages

class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [YourInline]

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        # TODO: check if this is the formset for the right inline 
        formset.save()
        effort = 0.0
        for assignment in formset.cleaned_data:
            if not assignment['DELETE']:
                effort += assignment['effort']
        if effort > form.instance.fte * 100:
            messages.warning(request, "Assignments exceed FTE equivalent")
```

Comment: I tried that. I had to move the save to the bottom though. Where you have it causes the following code to be skipped. Just saves the formset and leaves the function. When it's at the bottom the code executes, the message gets added but not displayed.

Comment: Did you install the middleware etc. as per documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages

Comment: Bingo, sk1p. I did not have the template setting. Just to dot the i's and cross the t's on this, I also had to override the default message level in order to get just warnings and errors.